# How to get exactly UTF-8 string in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, utf-8

I want to get UTF-8 string from code below:

```
String tmpStr= "ALMS_à¸à¸±à¹à¸à¸à¸­à¸à¸¥à¸à¸à¸°à¹à¸à¸µà¸¢à¸.pdf";
String fileName = new String(tmpStr.getBytes(), Charset.forName("UTF_8"));
```

But when I debug, the wrong value of fileName as below:
ALMS_�?ั�?�?�?อ�?ล�?�?ะ�?�?ีย�?.pdf
[image]

While I tested convert online, it worked normally:
[image]

Anyone can help me resolve the problem?
Thanks.
I am using eclipse to code java and I config encoding UTF-8 in it.

Comment: What exactly is the online tool doing? Can you give a link to the online tool?

Comment: https://cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/utf8_encode    The online tool here.

Comment: A Java string is **always** UTF-16, you need to create a byte array containing the UTF-8 bytes directly.

Comment: @greg-449 can you help me give " a byte array containing the UTF-8 bytes directly" ?

Comment: Where is the original UTF-8 data coming from? You need to get it as a byte array rather than a string.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know where are you getting from the initial string, but Java internally uses UTF-16 to represent Strings.

The use of encodings make sense when you need to `serialize` the String either to transmit over a connection, store it in a database, print it inside a text file, or on a webpage.

What is transmitted/stored/printed is a byte array representation of the String in the selected encoding.

The same when receiving/reading a value over a connection, file or database. You need to interpret the bytes in the correct encoding.

String provides a `getBytes()` method that get the representation of the String using the platform default encoding, it's not recommended because it makes the code platform dependent. You can provide the encoding either with a String, with `getBytes("UTF-8")` or a charset. Since Java 1.7, the `StandardCharsets` class provides shortcuts for the encodings that must suport the JVM, so you can use `getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

Now, your code should be something like this:

```
String tmpStr= "ALMS_à¸à¸±à¹à¸à¸à¸­à¸à¸¥à¸à¸à¸°à¹à¸à¸µà¸¢à¸.pdf";  
String fileName = new String(tmpStr.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

But this will not produce the String you are expecting, this will only get the UTF-8 byte representation of tmpStr, and create a new String representation reading that UTF-8 byte representation. So after this you can assert `tmpStr` is equal to `filename`.

I suspect the problem you are exposing is related to where are you reading the tmpStr value from, and what encoding is used to transform it in a String in the first place.

Comment: I tried derclaring `byte [] temp = tmpStr.getBytes("UTF_8");` but fileName return the String as tmpStr.

Comment: This just returns the UTF-16 string encoded as UTF-8 - it does not treat the original string as though it was already UTF-8.

Comment: the tmpStr value from Content-Disposotion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61242637/how-to-set-utf-8-for-file-upload-in-java

Comment: As I explained the filename attribute on Content-Disposition header only supports ISO-8859-1 encoding.